# Table in the Rmarkdown file does not render correctly (via RScript)

Tags: r, pdf, r-markdown, rscript

I am trying generate automated reports using `rmarkdown`, and final output expected is `pdf`.  However, when I run the script the resulting `.Rmd` file is okay, but the resulting `.pdf` file does not show the table.  It just shows the table as a list of values.  However, if I open the `.Rmd` file in `RStudio`, and use the `kint` button, I get a correctly formatted `pdf` file.  Has anyone seen this behaviour before? am I missing something?

````
    ---
    title: "RUO"
    author: "Me"
    date: "`r format(Sys.Date(), '%B %d, %Y')`"
    always_allow_html: true
    output:
      pdf_document:
      df_print: kable
      keep_tex: true
      latex_engine: lualatex
    header-includes:
      - \usepackage{graphicx}
      - \usepackage{fancyhdr}
      - \usepackage{float}
      - \usepackage{colortbl}
      - \usepackage[para,flushleft]{threeparttable}
      - \usepackage{fontspec}
      - \setmainfont{Raleway}
      - \AtBeginDocument{\let\maketitle\relax}
    classoption:
      - twocolumn
    ---
    \fancypagestyle{plain}{}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \addtolength{\headheight}{1.0cm}
    \rhead{Name: John Doe\\Sex: Male\\DoB: 01.01.01\\Lab \#: XXXXXXXX\\MRN \#: XXXXXXXX}

    ```{r setup, warning = FALSE, message = FALSE, echo = FALSE}
    knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, warning = FALSE, message = FALSE)
    library(tidyverse)
    library(stringi)
    library(DESeq2)
    library(kableExtra)
    ```

    ## This section is for Research Use Only

    ### Expression Table

    ```{r ExpTable}
    df <- data.frame(cbind("gene_name" = c("AAA", "BBB", "CCC"), 
                       "z-score" = c(-2, 2, 3)))
    df %>%
      setNames(c("Gene Name", "Z-score")) %>%
      as.data.frame() %>%
      # as_tibble() %>%
      knitr::kable(booktabs = T) %>%
      kableExtra::kable_styling(latex_options = c("hold_position", "striped")) # %>%
      # kableExtra::column_spec(2, width = "3 cm")
    ```


    \vfill


    ### Methodology

    Some Description 

    ### Comments and Limitations

    Disclosures.

    \clearpage
````

This code is the minimal example.  When you use something like:

```
    Rscript -e "library('knitr'); knitr::knit('filename.Rmd')"
```

The table does not render, but opening the same file in `RStudio`, renders is correctly.

---

##### UPDATE:

I realized after some more digging, that this is a un-reported bug (probably).  If you render a `rmarkdown` with a table to `pdf`, then it will usually render correctly.  But sometimes, the table is rendered as a `list` in the first render, and if you then render the same `.Rmd` to `pdf`, the table is rendered and correctly reformatted.  So if you render the same file twice, the second time all the tables are correctly rendered.  This happens more frequently if the only thing your file has a single table.

Comment: Add your code chunk with table, pls ;)

Comment: maybe try to knit your Rmarkdown with `rmarkdown::render` instead of `knit::knit`. kablextra pdf tables are rendered correctly for me.

Comment: @Guillaume, can you put it in as an answer, so I can accept it.